# Paypal rest sdk sandbox account still able to make payment after 0 funds

Tags: node.js, rest, paypal

I am using 'paypal-rest-sdk' in my node js webapp with react as frontend and integrated with 'paypal-checkout'. Everything working fine, fund was getting transfer but there only one problem when I tried to create an account that have fund less than what it is going to pay. the payment still going through in the callback i still see the state is {state: 'approved'} and in the store account i was seeing the money in increased but the buyer account is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that from my personal PayPal account I'll have no balance but I'll have linked bank accounts allowing payments made through PayPal to go through. It may be possible that it is mocking this feature.

Comment: It is hard to find but finally found it. all sandbox account is bound to infinite fund from paypal virtual bank